# how to get stock value by size and quantity and color one shot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have four models ( Item, Fabric, Production, stock)
and i want to get value of stock by item ID like that :

```
<table class="table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <td>Color</td>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="StockTbody"></tbody>
    </table>
```

**so that the values for the color and size are not repeated.**

fabric Model:

```
public class Fabric
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FabricName { get; set; }
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
   
    [Display(Name = "Color")]
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual Colors Colors { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FabricStore> fabricStore { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Production> production { get; set; }

}
```

Color Model:

```
public class Colors
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Color")]
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Fabric> fabric { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }


}
```

Item Model :

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Collection")]
    public Nullable<int> CollectionID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string BarcodeImage { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDraft { get; set; }
    public decimal SectoralSellingPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal wholesalePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal discountPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal wholesalevariegated { get; set; }
    public decimal DesignCost { get; set; }
    public int three { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Production> production { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection collection { get; set; }
    public virtual Categories categories { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> orderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

and this is stock model:

```
public class Stock
{
    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductionID { get; set; }
    public int SizeID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    
    public string ShelfNumber { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Production Production { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Size size { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StockRemain> stockRemain { get; set; }


}
```

this is my Controller:

```
public JsonResult StuckDetails (int ID)
    {
        var table = (from tb in db.Stocks
                     where ID == tb.Production.ItemID
                     select new
                     {
                         color = tb.Production.fabric.Colors.ColorName,
                         ColorId=tb.Production.fabric.ColorID,
                         size = tb.size.SizeName,
                         sizeID = tb.SizeID,
                         //Quantity = 
                     }).Distinct().ToList();
        
        return Json(table, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the problem is that : i want to sum Quantity
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `group by` here:

```
public JsonResult StuckDetails (int ID)
{
    var table = (from tb in db.Stocks
                 where ID == tb.Production.ItemID
                 group tb by new 
                 { 
                     tb.Production.fabric.Colors.ColorName, 
                     tb.size.SizeName
                 } into grp
                 select new
                 {
                     color = grp.Key.ColorName,
                     size =  grp.Key.SizeName,
                     Quantity = grp.Sum(g => g.Quantity)
                 });
    
    return Json(table, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

They `Key.ColorName` property name might vary - I'm not too sure here. Use Intellisense to guide you through it.